# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in eclipse

Tags: rest-assured

I created a json in my local machine and tried to access it via the server like below
[image]
[image]

It is working in the Postman but when I try to run through the code it is giving java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error.
Code as follows

```java
public class GetUsingLocalJson {
    @Test
    void testGet() throws Exception {
        given().when().get("http://localhost:3000/students").then().log().all();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me why it is failing in the code?
imports I have used is below

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestAssuredMockMvc Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782160/restassuredmockmvc-connection-to-http-localhost8080-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Set port as `RestAssured.port = 3000;`
`localhost` is set as baseURI by default.
Then simply call your endpoint like so:

```
given().when().get("/students").then().log().all();
```

Comment: Where to add RestAssured.port = 3000;?

Comment: for example in a startup method if you have class dedicated to RestAssured config. But it can simply be at the top of the test method, before your `given()...` expression.



[rest assured default values](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#default-values)




```public class GetUsingLocalJson {
    @Test
    void testGet() throws Exception {
        RestAssured.port = 3000;

        given().when().get("http://localhost:3000/students").then().log().all();
    }
}```